# "Вы": строчная и прописная

Tags: прописная-строчная

Подскажите, пожалуйста, со строчной или прописной пишется "вы" в подобном обороте: "Он вам с братом передавал привет" (обращение к человеку, с которым на "вы").
Спасибо

Answer (score 2):

В
 личной переписке вежливая форма "Вы" в русском языке может писаться как
 со строчной, так и с заглавной буквы. Обращение "вы" со строчной, 
вместо "ты" - это уже показатель уважения к собеседнику, но если хотите 
подчеркнуть особую степень расположения к нему, можете писать с заглавной.

Comment: Здесь, как я поняла, вопрос о другом. В данном конкретном случае речь не об одном человеке, а о двух. В обращении к нескольким людям "вы" пишется с маленькой буквы. Но одновременно тут и обращение к данному человеку.

Comment: @Fuchoin Kazuki, если к двум обращение, то в любом случае строчная, если к одному, то на выбор. Решить за автора обращаться ему только к одному человеку или сразу к нескольким я не могу.

Answer (score -1):

Я сторонник правописания этого личного местоимения в вежливом значении исключительно с прописной буквы: другое правило отсутствует. Если напишете по-другому, то, на мой взгляд, я бы расценил это как орфографическую ошибку.

Comment: http://web.archive.org/web/20081022205917/www.yandex.ru/info/you_full.html